# PHP and mySql - Two SELECT statements together in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have found a lot of answers regarding joining two `SELECT` statements using `UNION`.  However, I am trying to do something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT 'column' 
        FROM 'table' 
        WHERE 'id' = (
                        SELECT 'column' 
                        FROM 'another_table' 
                        WHERE 'id' = 'something_specific'
                    )"
```

Can this not be done or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is this generating an error by any chance, or was this just a carelessly written example

Comment: Ignoring the errors in your SQL, are you looking for `JOIN`?

Comment: Thanks, I'm deleting this question.  It was not mixing the statements that I was doing wrong.  I was not correctly using a php variable in the statement.  The statement is fine as I have generically written it.

Comment: That query contain errors. Read the duplicate-link

Comment: The single quote marks were just to determine names, I'm not actually using them in the query.  Sorry, I'm new to SQL and didn't fully understand the importance of the single quotes.

Comment: Also use MySQLi or PDO instead of MySQL because it is deprecated and you can easily get a SQL injection attack!